# Deserialize a JSON string in .NET

Tags: json, vb.net

I know there's a lot of questions about it here on **stackoverflow** but, I'm not being able to get the it working.

I have a JSON string ([Pastebin Link](https://pastebin.com/PsTPwzAi)).

I was trying to create a (simple and not completed) model to represent the JSON data just to debug it:

```
 Public Class games
    Public Property gameList() As String()
    Public Property gameId() As String
End Class
```

I really don't have an idea in how to do the complete model, seems very complicated to me.

Main code:

```
1| Dim jss As New JavaScriptSerializer()
2| Dim model As games = jss.Deserialize(Of games)(gameData)
3| MsgBox(model.gameId(0).ToString)
```

`gameData` is the JSON string.

I get an exception on the second line (`2|`..):
`Type 'System.String' is not supported for deserialization of an array.`

**Edit:**

I tried another way

```
 Public Class games
    Public Property gameId As Long
    Public Property mapId As Integer
    Public Property gameMode As String
    Public Property gameType As String
    Public Property gameQueueConfigId As Integer
    Public Property participants As String()
    Public Property observers() As String()
    Public Property platformId As String
    Public Property bannedChampions() As String()
    Public Property gameStartTime As Long
    Public Property gameLength As Long
End Class

Public Class wrapper
    Public gameList() As games
End Class

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim webClient As New System.Net.WebClient
    Dim gameData As String = webClient.DownloadString(
        "https://euw1.api.riotgames.com/lol/spectator/v3/featured-games?api_key=<key>")

    Dim json As String = gameData

    Dim gwrapper = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of wrapper)(json)
    Dim game = gwrapper.gameList

    If game.Length = 1 Then
        MsgBox(game(0).gameMode)
    End If
End Sub
```

**I get an exception:**
`Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: {. Path 'gameList[0].participants', line 1, position 133.`

Comment: @PurTahan Are you sure? because I want to `Deserialize` the string

Comment: use **Below**...

Comment: There are a lot of utils there, for example: [https://jsonutils.com/](https://jsonutils.com/) will convert json to vb.net classes

Comment: @Fabio That's really helpful! Thank you for your comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got to an anwser just searching a little more!

```
    Public Class games
    Public Property gameId As Long
    Public Property mapId As Integer
    Public Property gameMode As String
    Public Property gameType As String
    Public Property gameQueueConfigId As Integer
    Public Property participants As participants()
    Public Property observers As observers
    Public Property platformId As String
    Public Property bannedChampions As banned()
    Public Property gameStartTime As Long
    Public Property gameLength As Long
End Class
Public Class participants
    Public Property teamId As Integer
    Public Property spell1Id As Integer
    Public Property spell2Id As Integer
    Public Property championId As Integer
    Public Property profileIconId As Integer
    Public Property summonerName As String
    Public Property bot As Boolean
End Class
Public Class observers
    Public Property encryptionKey As String
End Class
Public Class banned
    Public Property championId() As Integer
    Public Property teamId() As Integer
    Public Property pickTurn() As Integer
End Class
Public Class wrapper
    Public gameList() As games
End Class

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim webClient As New System.Net.WebClient
    Dim gameData As String = webClient.DownloadString(
        "https://euw1.api.riotgames.com/lol/spectator/v3/featured-games?api_key=<key>")

    Dim json As String = gameData

    Dim gwrapper = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of wrapper)(json)
    Dim game = gwrapper.gameList

    MsgBox(game(0).mapId.ToString)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use [Newtonsoft.Json](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/).

```
Dim x As String = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(GameObj)
Dim obj As games = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(GameStr)
```

edit:

```
Public Class myObj
    Public gameList() As game
    Public clientRefreshInterval As Integer
End Class

Public Class game
    Public gameId As Integer
    Public mapId As Integer
    Public gameMode As String
    Public gameType As String
    Public gameQueueConfigId As Integer
    Public participants() As participant
    Public observers As observer
    Public platformId As String
    Public bannedChampions() As bannedChampion
    Public gameStartTime As Integer
    Public gameLength As Integer
End Class

Public Class participant
    Public teamId As Integer
    Public spell1Id As Integer
    Public spell2Id As Integer
    Public championId As Integer
    Public profileIconId As Integer
    Public summonerName As String
    Public bot As Boolean
End Class

Public Class observer
    Public encryptionKey As String
End Class

Public Class bannedChampion
    Public championId As Integer
    Public teamId As Integer
    Public pickTurn As Integer
End Class
```

Comment: Look's a simple solution, but I'm having problems creating the data structure/model of the JSON string I have, can you give me some advice/tip/example ?

Comment: can you put your Json string hear?

Comment: You create code blocks by indenting every line of code by four (4) spaces (you can also select all code and press `CTRL + K`). Using the backticks \` is just for `inline code` (code inside the current line of regular text), _**not**_ for code that occupies _**more than one line**_. For more information see the [Markdown and Formatting help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Comment: OP already using `Newtonsoft.Json` in line `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of wrapper)(json)`.